# AWS Lambda | Read Multiple Files from S3 | Create combined JSON | Facing performance issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am reading multiple JSON files from S3 on AWS lambda and finally creating one JSON after some processing, I am able to read the files and combined them but seems its not optimal way to optimize minimum IO operation, I am facing performance hit when the file size is big.

here my simplified code

```
exports.handler = function (e, callback) {
    helper.data.readJSON(s3_param)
        .then(function (data_1) {
            var data_1 = JSON.parse(data_1);
            helper.data.readJSON(s3_param)
                .then(function (data_2) {
                    var data_2 = JSON.parse(data_2);
                    helper.data.readJSON(s3_param)
                        .then(function (data_3) {
                            var data_3 = JSON.parse(data_3);
                            return SomeFuntion(data_1, data_2, data_3);
                        });
                });
        });
};
```

this is readJSON code which read file from S3

```
async function readJSON(params) {
        const data = (await (S3.getObject(params).promise())).Body.toString('utf-8');
        return data;
    }
```

can someone please suggest better way to do it.

Comment: Avoid the promise-as-callback antipattern, return each Promise to be consumed by the next outer `.then` instead

Comment: I will suggest you look at Amazon Athena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do things in parallel using `Promise.all`. something like

```
async function readJSON(params) {
  const data = (await (S3.getObject(params).promise())).Body.toString('utf-8');
  return JSON.parse(data);
}

exports.handler = async event => {
  const [data_1, data_2, data_3] = await Promise.all([
    readJSON(s3_param1),
    readJSON(s3_param2),
    readJSON(s3_param3)
  ]);
  return someFunction(data_1, data_2, data_3);
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me and at least I am 50-70 milliseconds improvement in terms of performance, this is about 10% reduction of consumed time.